# viewstate remains empty when string is assigned

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am assigning text to View state and using it in another, event but the viewstate remains empty, why ?

```
if (txtSelectedID.Text != "")
{
    string ComplaintCode = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Text);
    txtAssignComplaintCode.Text = ComplaintCode;
    ViewState["ComposeLetterSubject"] = txtSubject.Text + " " + "Complaint Code:" + " " + ComplaintCode;

}
```

Comment: The view state can be use on the post back, where did you try to read it ?

Comment: i am using it in update event like

string Subject = Convert.ToString(ViewState["ComposeLetterSubject"]);

Comment: what event u tried to read it?

Comment: update event like this 

string Subject = Convert.ToString(ViewState["ComposeLetterSubject"]);

Comment: The viewstate is there on PostBack. If you try to read it on post back and fail, check 1. Is viewstate for the control enable ? 2. Is viewstate for the page enable ? 3. Debug your code to be sure that you st a value.

Comment: can i use Session instead of ViewState[""], is it feasible ?